# Android: Implemented onClickListener, NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-widget

it might be my limited experience, but I just ran into a weird error which confuses me. I have an Activity with a bunch of buttons which are then assigned into a 2-Dimensional Array (btns[][]). Initially, I used to set an OnClick Listener by using an anonymous class, which would basically be the following, for each and every button:

```
btns[x][y].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(() {
    onClick(View v) {
        btns_OnClick(x, y, btns[x][y]);
    }
```

Not that x and y in this case were hard coded constants.

Since this was really bugging me, I implemented:

```
private class TimerButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    int[] crds;

    public TimerButtonOnClickListener(int row, int col) {
        crds = new int[] { row, col };
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        btns_OnClick(crds[0], crds[1],
        btns[crds[0]][crds[1]]);
    }
}
```

And assign the Listener to the Buttons as follows:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            btns[i][j].setOnClickListener(new TimerButtonOnClickListener(i, j));
```

The above happens in onCreate, yet the crash does not occur immediately. Actually, I have no Idea where it crashes. LogCat gives

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1061)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1078)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use a handler to invoke a ui update from a Timer Task, but even if I remove the timer I still receive this error, so its probably not my own Handler breaking there.

I did not make any changes to the source apart from that. (I even diff'd, and I also didn't touch any other file.)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: that error is not related to your buttons, the NPE happens while the system tries to start some `Service`. Do you bind to a service somewhere? Possibly using a `null` `ServiceConnection`?

Comment: You're right, and I'm kind of an idiot for committing two changes after another, accidently removing the ServiceConnection's initialization in the first one and wondering about how the diff doesn't point me at it. You just saved my day! (Which is a VERY good thing at 00:48 ;))

Comment: @zapl You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not related to buttons. The stacktrace would mention "button", "onClick" or something button related if that was the case.

Instead the `NullPointerException` happens while the system connects to a `Service`. Looking at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/LoadedApk.java#LoadedApk.ServiceDispatcher.doConnected%28android.content.ComponentName%2Candroid.os.IBinder%29) for the place where the exception happens

> at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1061)

```
if (service != null) {
    // mConnection is a ServiceConnection
    mConnection.onServiceConnected(name, service); // 1061
}
```

one can see that it is most likely related to [Context#bindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) with a `null` `ServiceConnection`